# Create Python Package with Single PYD File

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, package

I have a single `pyd` file (dynamically linked library), say `MyPackage.pyd`. When putting it in the same folder as my `py` scripts I can simply do `import MyPackage` and then use its functions via `MyPackage.FUNC` (where FUNC is any function name).

How do I package this `pyd` file up into a folder under `\PYTHONPATH\Lib\site-packages\` so that I can do `import MyPackage` without having to have the `pyd` file in the same folder as my scripts anymore?

My guess is I need to create a folder `\PYTHONPATH\Lib\site-packages\MyPackage\`, copy `MyPackage.pyd` into it, and then create a `__init__.py` file in there. But I am unsure what to write into this file?

Question [Include *.pyd files in Python Packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37031456/include-pyd-files-in-python-packages) didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: This helped indeed. Almost too easy.

Comment: You should accept my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put the pyd file in site-pacakges folder (not in any subfolder there). It should work!